# What is meant by "plant" in control system?

Tags: control, control-system, terminology

What is meant by "plant" in control system? Does it also means systems like DC motor or it only includes large systems like chemical (fertilizer or cement) plant?

Comment: see also: [Why is it called "plant"?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/67640/13320)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, as Marko writes, it can be just a DC motor. In general it's "the thing being controlled".

In fact the word "plant" in plain English can mean

- "factory", as the OP points out (Cement factory)

and closer to the field of control theory it can also mean

- "machines", without the factory building

For instance "the heating plant for a home" or "nuclear plant for a submarine"; https://www.dictionary.com/browse/plant

I'll let the linguists battle it out, but it does origin from the word for "shrub", which rooted in soil, with branches, leaves etc.. and if you look at a **power plant** or **heating plant**, they look like that too: mounted to the ground, with protruding tubes, boxes etc.... so maybe plant -the machine- came before plant -the factory.

See also the comment by *Ross*, who found the etymology back to the 18th century: "at first with reference to the machinery, tools, apparatus, etc., later also the building"

There's something that connects the non-mobile machine, installed at a factory, with feed pipes, exhaust pipes etc..., with the rooted, and thus obviously non-mobile, plant.

And according to *Andrew* (see comments), in British English it's quite common to refer to heavy and mobile machinery like bulldozers, graders, and road rollers as "**heavy plant**"

[image]

Image: https://thoughtsbyanidlemind.wordpress.com/2013/02/15/thoughts-on-heavy-plant-crossing/

Comment: So it's *called* plant based on the "factory" meaning, but it doesn't have to actually be a factory.

Comment: @user253751 I'll let the linguists battle it out, but it does origin from the word for "shrub", rooted with branches, leaves etc.. and if you look at a power plant or heating plant, they look like that too: mounted to the ground, with protruding tubes, boxes etc.... so maybe plant -the machine- came before plant -the factory-.

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=plant ... `Most extended usages are from the verb, on the notion of "something planted;" such as "construction for an industrial process," 1789, at first with reference to the machinery, tools, apparatus, etc., later also the building; also slang meaning "a spy" (1812). Many of these follow similar developments in the French form of the word.`

Comment: And there's also "heavy plant" such as bulldozers, graders, and road rollers, leading the slightly amusing road warning sign "Heavy plant crossing".

Comment: Awesome @AndrewMorton, I'll have to update my answer!

Comment: @RossPresser, good find. Any thoughts whether "circuit" in EE precedes (18th cent. according to etymonline) or succeeds "circuit" in a process involving liquids?

Comment: @P2000 sorry, no, I don't have an answer for that.

Comment: Another example -- In HVAC the set of chillers or boilers / heat pumps and pumps, valves, control devices etc. is commonly referred to as a "plant". These devices are generally controlled as a system.

Comment: And most of the devices @UuDdLrLrSs refers to, along with others, are likely to be found in a "plant room".  A lift (elevator) may also have its own plant room at the top of the shaft (or on the roof)

Answer (score 7):

It could be anything that has an input and gives an output. In control theory is depicted as a box with a relation Output VS. Input, we call this transfer function. It may have also multiple inputs and/or multiple outputs.

The physical size is not important, so yes your DC motor could also be a plant.